# Adobe Flash Catalyst to author AIR 2.0 applications

Tags: air, flash-builder

Has anyone used [Adobe Flash Catalyst](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashcatalyst/) to to author [AIR 2.0](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air.html) applications ?  Flash Catalyst allows to save a project in [fxp format](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSbde04e3d3e6474c4ef5411412477fbf920-8000.html) which can be imported by [Flash Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Flash_Builder) and then run on the Flash Player runtime. I want it to run on the [Adobe Air debug runtime](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf5f9ca-7ffe.html) and then create as a Windows desktop application . But Catalyst doesn't seem to support that. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

After completing your application in catalyst cs5 you can 
click file menu, choose publish for swf or air and select build air application
You can also uncheck build version for upload to a web sever
Now you have air file and can install it